# Is there a name for the pattern of injecting implementations into a portable class library?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, architecture, portable-class-library

Apologies for the not entirely code related question.

I am in the process of building a WPF application with a View Model Locator pattern. In that I have interfaces to represent functionality not present in portable class libraries.

I then assign those properties concrete values in my application so that they are available for injection to my view models.

My question is, do we have a name for this pattern? It seems a standard enough way to do this but I am never sure what to call it and end up having to explain it every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A term Microsoft uses to describe the way one can inject in a PCL concrete implementations of code that cannot be written to directly target a PCL is [platform abstraction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn641187(v=vs.110).aspx).

There are several techniques to achieve this. Here are some useful links:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx
- http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/11/portable-class-library-enlightenment.html
- http://log.paulbetts.org/the-bait-and-switch-pcl-trick/

Comment: I'm using MVVM Light, Simple IoC - sorry, I'm asking more generically what do we call this technique of passing concretions to a portable class library?

Comment: Are you looking for the term [platform abstraction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn641187(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I think I am :) Put as answer and I'll mark it - the old case of knowing what something is but not enough to google.